# deleteNode for singly linked list java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

```
public void deleteNode(Student targetNode) {

    Node position = head;
    Node nextPosition1;
    Node nextPosition2;

    while (position.getLink() != null) {

        if (position.getLink().getData().equals(targetNode)) {

            nextPosition1 = position.getLink();
            nextPosition2 = nextPosition1.getLink();
            position.setLink(nextPosition2);

        } else {
            position = position.getLink(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I can delete specific nodes but can't delete the first node.

Comment: maybe in your else you should just set head to null?

Comment: Just add a check before you start iterating through the array for equality between the two, and if that's the case then set head to the 2nd element in the list, and remove the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is always checking the **next** link in your position for equality with your target node. Thus, it'll never look at the first value (the head). The easiest way to fix this is just add a clause to check for equality explicitly against the head, and if it exists, advance the head to the it's link otherwise enter your while loop that checks against all future links. I believe you would also want to add a `break;` to the if clause where you remove the link unless you're looking to actually potentially remove several nodes and not just one (as your function name would suggest).

```
public void deleteNode(Student targetNode) {
    Node position = head;
    if (position.getData().equals(targetNode)) {
        head = position.getLink();
    }
    else {

        Node nextPosition1;
        Node nextPosition2;
        while (position.getLink() != null) {

            if (position.getLink().getData().equals(targetNode)) {

                nextPosition1 = position.getLink();
                nextPosition2 = nextPosition1.getLink();
                position.setLink(nextPosition2);

            } else {
                position = position.getLink(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The alternative is to check the current position (keeping track of the previous Node) and remove it once it's equal to the targetNode. If the previous node is null, then we know we're looking at the head (and should update the head), else we're looking at a middle/end link in the list.

```
public void deleteNode(Student targetNode) {
    Node position = head;
    Node previous = null;
    while (position != null) {
    {
        if (position.getData().equals(targetNode)) {
            if (previous == null) {
                head = position.getLink();
            }
            else {
                previous.setLink(position.getLink());
            }
            break;
        }
        else {
            previous = position;
            position = position.getLink();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great works fine! thanks for your help!